# Use the last V3 Selenium: Last Chromedriver and last Chrome Browser

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

If I continue to use the latest version of Selenium V3. What is the latest version of Chromedriver and Chrome Browser that I can use?

I dont want use Selenium 4 for now.

Thx

Answer (score 0):

You can use any version of Chrome browser with appropriate Chromedriver version. Also the latest Chrome and Chromedriver and not the latest. You can use both Selenium 3 and Selenium 4, there is no limitation or any kind of enforcement to use Selenium 4 at least for now.